# Is there a difference between "enmesh" and "entangle"?

Tags: differences

Is there a difference between these two words? If yes, what is it?

From Oxford English Dictionary,

> enmesh
>
> 1. transitive. To surround with meshes; to catch or entangle in, or as in, a net. Also of the net, and fig.
> 2. fig. To entrap, entangle; to make (thought) complicated.

Enmesh seems to be very similar to entangle. What is the minor difference between them, if not subtle?

Comment: I'm flagging this as off-topic ("no research / ELL"). Hi xuhdev, did you consult a dictionary before you asked here? Our [Help Centre](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) says "Be sure to [mention the research you've done](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/a/5043) and what you're still hoping to learn!" For further guidance, see [ask]. :-)

Comment: "Enmesh" implies a certain degree of order.

Comment: Enmeshed gears: https://duckduckgo.com/?q=enmeshed+gears&t=ffsb&ia=web

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your own quoted definition:

> enmesh
>
> 1. transitive. To surround with meshes; to catch or entangle in, or as in, a net. Also of the net, and fig.

whereas [entangle](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/entangle) means:

> 1. Cause to become twisted together with or caught in.

Therefore entangling in a net is enmeshing. But you can entangle two pieces of string together, or entangle someone in a rope; there's no mesh/net here, so it's not enmeshing.